# How do I remove the reference to Twilio in my emails?

Tags: email

How do I remove the reference to Twilio in my emails?

We have set up Twilio SendGrid Email service integration to send emails. But I am seeing "
♥ POWERED BY TWILIO SENDGRID" at the bottom of the email that we receive.

Is there any way to remove this?